# How do I find good motels on a trip from California to Alabama?

Tags: usa, accommodation, road-trips

The total distance is around 2300 miles.I am thinking of the following:

Drive probably 500 miles per day and stay at motel over night and then start next day for another 500 miles drive How should I figure out if a particular motel is good or not?If anyone has experience driving same number of miles in the same direction, please share or advise.

Comment: I would pick a chain, join its membership/rewards club, and stick with it for the entire trip. That will provide you with a guide, ensure you have a decent way to complain if needed, be (relatively) assured of similar cleanliness, and get you rewards as well. Plus the hotline can help with reservations for the future nights.

Comment: If it's open, it will probably be good enough. But 500 miles is a short day; expect to drive more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found reviews at Trip Advisor and, especially, Booking.com to be reliable. You can get mobile apps for both.

The idea of sticking to one chain is also reasonable, but it might be difficult in some of the less populated areas.

Off topic, on that route I recommend making a detour to as many National Parks of the Southwest as possible.

Answer (score 6):

How 'good' do you need it to be?

A room at any of the major hotel chains will be a clean, comfortable sleeping spot.

Smaller mom & pop places can be nice as well, I usually check their outside appearance first... clean parking lot, hanging plants, a bit of outside furniture.

Most small motels will let you see the room before paying.